# Web API Multiple get with int[] not working

Tags: c#, .net, http, asp.net-web-api

In my `Web API` project I have an API controller - `ValuesController`.

In the Values Controller I have the following actions:

```
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        var result = new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        return Json(result);
    }

    public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
    {
        var data = new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        return Json(data);
    }
```

The code inside the action methods are just dummy.
These action methods are hit and are working fine when i Try the following URLs:
http://localhost:25901/api/values
http://localhost:25901/api/values/1

Now I add the following action method:

```
    public IHttpActionResult Get([FromUri] int[] idList)
    {
        var data = new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        return Json(data);
    }
```

Now when I hit the following URL:
http://localhost:25901/api/values
I get the following error:

> {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Multiple
>   actions were found that match the request: \r\nGet on type
>   WebAPITryouts.Controllers.ValuesController\r\nGet on type
>   WebAPITryouts.Controllers.ValuesController","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","StackTrace":"
>   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector.ActionSelectorCacheItem.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext
>   controllerContext)\r\n at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext
>   controllerContext)\r\n at
>   System.Web.Http.ApiController.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext
>   controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()"}

The webApi config is as follows:

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Please advice

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to pass some ids to filter all values. Currently problems is that from routing point of view you have two actions which map to exactly same route:

```
api/values
```

There is no route with `idList` parameter. So `idList` does not affect routing. You have two possible solutions here.

1. You can leave both methods, but teach routing to distinguish them.
2. You can leave only one method and use `idList` as optional filter.

I personally prefer second solution.

```
    [ResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<string>))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get([FromUri] int[] idList)
    {
        var values = Enumerable.Range(1, 10);
        if (idList.Any()) // use optional filter e.g. pass to repository
            values = values.Where(i => idList.Contains(i));

        return Ok(values.Select(i => $"value{i}").ToList());
    }
```

Also consider to use custom model binder to pass array as comma delimited values.